# Alerts on calendars with overlays

Tags: calendar, notifications, overlay

SP 2013. I have a calendar that aggregates a couple of calendars of its sub sites. That works fine. If I set an alert on this top calendar I won't get notified about new events being "added" by overlayed calendars.

Did someone encounter such a use case? Which options do I have here?

Answer (score 2):

It is by design. The other 2 calendars are separate calendars and you should set alerts on them too. Calendar overlays do not 'merge' data.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Well that's what I was afraid.. it seems one solution might be to have a workflow "physically" add to the top calendar.

Comment: I am in a similar situation. My calendar overlays are based on different views of the same calendar. My way the alert is sent whenever anything is added on the other 'overlays'. I only had to add a category column. From a end user perspective, the only difference is that they are not located in different subsites.